# Generate tag in dynamic way in xQuery

Tags: xquery

how can I generate tags from sequence in dynamic way? I mean that I have

sequence like

```
let $names = ("name1", "name2", "name3");
```

and I want to create

```
<name1>

</nam1>

<name2>

</name2>

<name3>

</name3
```

How can I do this?

Comment: You already know how to construct the elements from the answers to your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51132819/what-is-the-element-constructor-in-xquery). So just loop through your sequence of names and return the constructed elements.

Answer (score 2):

Use a [dynamic element constructor](https://www.w3.org/TR/2017/REC-xquery-31-20170321/#id-computedElements):

```
('a','b') ! element {.} {()}
```