# XQuery - Select and display child nodes using a pattern

Tags: xpath, xquery

I launched test from SoapUI and I want to figure out an XQuery assert. I am not able to write the XQuery request.

**My xml file** (answer request SoapUI)

```
<parent>
  <total1>10.000</total1>
  <total2>15</total2>
  <value1>1</value1>
  <value2>2</value2>
</parent>
```

**Expected answer**

I want only nodes starting with total, and the number value of node value

```
<parent>
  <total1>10.0</total1>
  <total2>15.0</total2>
</parent>
```

**Current not working XQuery request**

```
<parent>
{ for $n in //parent/*[starts-with(name(),'total')]
 return ($n/name() ,$n/number(text()) )
}
</parent>
```

This is not right because it display only node name. All nodes are on the same line : `<parent> total1 10.0 total2 15.0 </parent>`
I am OK to do it using XQuery or XPath

Comment: Did you try `<parent>
{ for $n in //parent/*[starts-with(name(),'total')]
 return ($n)}
</parent>` ?

Comment: With this pattern I am not able to use function number(). I also get all links xmlns:... that it is not human readable.

Comment: Add XML sample similar to your real source file. Provided simplified XML might confuse answerers

Comment: I agree with you, but I am not sure I want to do that because it is from my company WS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

New element nodes can be created with [element constructors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51132819/what-is-the-element-constructor-in-xquery):

```
<parent>{
  for $n in //parent/*[starts-with(name(), 'total')]
  return element { name($n) } { number($n) }
}</parent>
```

The function call `number(<total1>10.000</total1>)` yields `10` instead of `10.0`. If you need a customized representation of your numeric values, the `format-number` function can be used:

```
<parent>{
  for $n in //parent/*[starts-with(name(), 'total')]
  return element { name($n) } { format-number(number($n), '#.0') }
}</parent>
```