# Using XQuery to create data table

Tags: xml

I'm trying to format some data for a character generator. I've already got the data coming from a UDP stream into the CG as XML but now it needs to have some XQuery stuff run on it to format it. Here is an example of the data I have:

```
        <root>
      <element>
        <L></L>
      </element>
      <element>
        <L>0</L>
        <Name>Diana Prahoveanu</Name>
        <Club>Essex</Club>
        <Time>40</Time>
        <P>10</P>
        <Lap>C</Lap>
      </element>
      <element>
        <L></L>
      </element>
      <element>
        <L>1</L>
        <Name>Emily Cocksedge</Name>
        <Club>Hertford</Club>
        <Time>35.85</Time>
        <P>1</P>
        <Lap>F</Lap>
      </element>
      <element>
        <L></L>
      </element>
```

I don't know what kind of XQuery code is required to format this into its 6 columns.

Thanks!

Now, if I add some data back to the start of the XML. it still only shows the 6 columns.

```
<root>
  <element>
    <col1>S604</col1>
    <col2>Dual in the Pool</col2>
    <col3>Top Club(Evt.5),USA 30, EAS 22</col3>
  </element>
  <element>
    <col1></col1>
  </element>
  <element>
    <col1>Event 101 Womens Open 50m Freestyle Heat 4</col1>
  </element>
  <element>
    <col1></col1>
  </element>
  <element>
    <col1>49</col1>
  </element>
  <element>
    <col1></col1>
  </element>
  <element>
    <col1>L</col1>
    <col2>Name</col2>
    <col3>Club</col3>
    <col4>Time</col4>
    <col5>P</col5>
    <col6>Lap</col6>
  </element>
  <element>
    <col1></col1>
  </element>
  <element>
    <col1>0</col1>
    <col2>Diana Prahoveanu</col2>
    <col3>Essex</col3>
    <col4>40</col4>
    <col5>10</col5>
    <col6>C</col6>
    <col7/>
  </element>
  <element>
    <col1></col1>
  </element>
  <element>
    <col1>1</col1>
    <col2>Emily Cocksedge</col2>
    <col3>Hertford</col3>
    <col4>35.85</col4>
    <col5>1</col5>
    <col6>F</col6>
    <col7/>
  </element>
```

Comment: What is your environment? What language you are using?

Comment: Can you post an example of the desired output, to understand what you are trying to achieve? (i.e. CSV with/without headers)

Comment: This is in some software called Characterworks and this is the only bit about it on their documentation:
"It is also possible to extract keys and values from local or web-based XML or JSON resources. For processing of the XML or JSON content, XQuery is used. XQuery is a standardized language for finding and extracting elements and attributes from XML documents. The power of the XQuery language makes it possible to perform a wide-range of filtering, sorting and preprocessing operations on the input data." Essentially, it just needs to be a 6x10 table.

Comment: that still doesn't help. What format is your table? HTML table, a CSV, or what?

Comment: http://chrworks.com/help/?url=doc/XMLJSONDataSource.html seems that it should be `<row>
 <column1>value1</column1>
 <column2>value2</column2>
 ...
</row>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to http://chrworks.com/help/?url=doc/XMLJSONDataSource.html

> it is expected that the XQuery is written so that the output will conform to the following general structure:

```
<row>
 <column1>value1</column1>
 <column2>value2</column2>
 ...
</row>
```

Assuming that the XML was in a variable called `$doc` and you only want to produce rows for the `element` that have those 6 child elements, ignoring the `element` that have the empty `<L></L>`:

```
for $row in $doc/root/element
where count($row/*) eq 6
return
  element {"row"} {
    for $col in $row/*
    return element {$col/local-name()} {$col/data()}
  }
```

Produces:

```
<row>
  <L>0</L>
  <Name>Diana Prahoveanu</Name>
  <Club>Essex</Club>
  <Time>40</Time>
  <P>10</P>
  <Lap>C</Lap>
</row>
<row>
  <L>1</L>
  <Name>Emily Cocksedge</Name>
  <Club>Hertford</Club>
  <Time>35.85</Time>
  <P>1</P>
  <Lap>F</Lap>
</row>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It's been driving me mad for the last few days. I don't still quite get how you arrived at that but it's given me a good start to mess around with.

Comment: I can add some detail to the answer to try to explain further if there is something in particular that you don't understand. It uses XPath to address pieces of the document, for loops over the selected items, and an element constructor https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51132819/what-is-the-element-constructor-in-xquery

Comment: I've re-added some data to the start of the XML that a removed whilst trying to make it easier to begin with. Tried a few things but it ignores anything with less that 6 columns?

Comment: Yes. You can remove the `where` clause and find a different way to filter out the `element` that only had the empty `col1` or `L` elements. If you want to generate output for them, then remove it completely. Otherwise, find a different filter criteria to test (such as, does it have any child elements with `text()` that isn't just whitespace.